# Read multiple variables from data object returned with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I am making a jquery ajax call to an mvc controller. I want to return 2 or more variables from the controller. How do I package data in controller for this ? how do I extract with jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your controller action, use the built in Json method :

```
return Json(new {name1 = "value1", name2 = "value2"});
```

And your jQuery call :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/your-url",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {data: to_send},
    success: function(msg) {
       alert(msg.name1);
       alert(msg.name2);
    }
});
//you can of course use another ajax function jQuery provides.
```